# Funcion en PHP se activa sin llamarla

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una función en `PHP` que se activa mediante un `onclick` de un texto, y funciona perfectamente. Lo que pasa es que la función también se activa cuando se carga la página

```html
    <div class="container p-5" style="text-align:center;">
        <h4>Has creado tu cuenta!</h4>
        <p>Hemos enviado un email a la dirección que nos has proporcionado para activar tu cuenta.</p>
        <p>Si no has recibido el email de activación, haz click <a href="" onclick="enviarEmail();">aquí</a></p>
        <p id="enviarEmail"></p>
    </div>

<script>
  function enviarEmail(){
    document.write('<?php echo enviarE(); ?>');
  }
</script>

<?php
    
   function enviarE(){    
      require_once 'app/conexion.php';
      $result;
      $conn = dbConnect();
      $para  = $_GET['email'];
 
       
     // Asunto
     $titulo = 'Activar cuenta';
 
     // Cuerpo
     ob_start();

     $checkCode = "SELECT claveVerify FROM empresa WHERE email = '$para'";
     $result = $conn->query($checkCode);
     $rows = $result->fetchAll();
  
 
     foreach ($rows as $row) {
  
         $verifyCode = $row['claveVerify']; 

     } 



     $mensaje = '<table style="background:black;"><td width="35%" 
     style="background:white;">';
     $mensaje .= '<h1 style="text-align:center;">Bienvenido, <span 
     style="color:#4160A7;">' . $nombre . '</span></h1>';
     $mensaje .= '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Activa tu cuenta 
     ahora</h4>';
     $mensaje .= '<p style="text-align:center;"><a 
     href="https://****.com/php/verifyAccountGo.php?verifyCode=' . 
     $verifyCode . '&email=' . $para . '">Activar</a></p>';
     $mensaje .= '</td></table>';

     $cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
     $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
     $cabeceras .= 'From: <no-reply@*****.com>' . "\r\n";

    mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);

}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué devuelve la función `enviarE()`? Porque veo que la estás haciendo un `echo` pero sin saber lo que está pintando es difícil predecir lo que está sucediendo.

Comment: Acabo de añadir la función enviarE() completa

Comment: Se va a ejecutar porque lo tienes entre <script> ese se va a ejecutar SIEMPRE, luego, si le das al botón se ejecuta el otro, como solución, quítalo ponle una boolean etc..

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de como hacerlo con un booleano?

Comment: @Tefef Debes tener en cuenta que todo el código php se v a ejecutar antes de que se cargue la página y que javascript y php no pueden interaccionar de forma directa como pretendes aparentemente hacer.

Comment: `function enviarEmail(){
    document.write('<?php echo enviarE(); ?>');
  }' Ese `echo` se va a ejecutar siempre cuando cargue la página debido a que **PHP** no sabe que se encuentra dentro de una función de Javascript, para **PHP** no existe ese código. La solución sería realizar esta comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor con una llamada AJAX.

Comment: @Tefef Recuerda que js y php **SI** pueden interactuar, y que  `document.write('<?php echo enviarE(); ?>');` es correcto.  (quedaría  _document.write('1');_) y se ejecutaría siempre que llames a la `function EnviarEmail()`. Debes de tener algun otro error. Intenta completar la pregunta con toda la información `html/php/js`

Comment: @Roy Ese es todo mi código, a excepción del head y footer